# Umbraco count active content pages

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

I would like to get a count of pages in nodes in an Umbraco site with output something like this:

- Root (9 subnodes)

  - First Folder (4 subnodes)

    - document 1
    - document 2
    - document 3
    - document 4
  - Second Folder (3 subnodes)

    - document 1
    - document 2
    - document 3

Basically I am trying to see how much active content there is in a given site and come up with a way to divide the work. Is there a reasonable way to get this information?

Comment: "Active" as in Published?

Comment: Yes. Published content.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

- Descendants.cs in App_Code folder

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using umbraco.presentation;
  using umbraco.presentation.nodeFactory;

  public static class ExtensionMethods
  {
      public static IEnumerable<Node> AllDescendants(this Node node)
      {
          foreach (Node child in node.Children)
          {
              yield return child;

              foreach (Node grandChild in child.AllDescendants())
                  yield return grandChild;
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Razor View

  ```
  @inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
  @using umbraco.presentation.nodeFactory;
  @{
     Layout = "";
  }

  @functions{
     public string CreateSitemap()
     {
          var temp = "<ul class='collapsibleList'>" + sitemap(-1) + "</ul>" + Environment.NewLine;
         return temp;
     }

  public string sitemap(int nodeID)
  {
      var rootNode = new umbraco.presentation.nodeFactory.Node(nodeID);
      var sitemapstring = "<li>" + rootNode.Name + " (" + rootNode.AllDescendants().Count() + ") <span style='font-size:9px'>" + rootNode.NodeTypeAlias + "</span></li>" + Environment.NewLine;

  if (rootNode.Children.Count > 0)
  {
      sitemapstring += "<ul>" + Environment.NewLine;
      sitemapstring = rootNode.Children.Cast<Node>().Aggregate(sitemapstring, (current, node) => current + sitemap(node.Id));
      sitemapstring += "</ul>" + Environment.NewLine;
  }
  return sitemapstring;
  }
  }
  <body>
   @Html.Raw(CreateSitemap())
  </body>
  ```